# Infinite sum and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation, fourier-analysis

Is there a closed formula for the sum $$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2 \pi i n x}}{n^{a+1}} $$ ? $(a \in (0,1))$

My goal is to show that the series $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ defined by $a_k = \int_0^1 r(x)^k dx$, where $r(x)=\frac{1}{\zeta(1+a)} \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2 \pi i n x}}{n^{a+1}}$converges.

Comment: Even for $x=0$, $a=1/2$, there's no closed form for $\sum_1^{\infty}n^{-3/2}$.

Comment: I've answered a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3605895) lately. Where does it come from?

Comment: It comes from random walks and Toeplitz matrices for the walks. There is a formula through Fourier analysis for the powers of these matrices and therefore for the steps needed to a certain point of the random walk.